# Jquery Remove the details inside tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm currently using jQuery `$('#status').remove();` to remove the detail of my

`<p id="status"DETAILS!!!!></p>` But what I need is just to remove the data inside of my tag not the tag itself. Is there any script or way to do it?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/empty/. The jQuery documentation is organised quite well. This one appears under the [DOM Removal](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-removal/) category

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, to remove inner HTML with jQuery is as simple as:

```
$("#status").empty();
```

Check out this link for more info:
https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#status").empty();
```

This might be your solution since `$("selector").remove()` removes all the Elements associated with the selected tag while `$("selector").empty()` removes everything inside the selected tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$('#status').text('');` to clear the text inside your tag

Answer (score 1):

you could try

If your div looks like this:

```
<div id="status">content in here</div>


status = document.getElementById("#status")

status.innerHTML = '';
```

It will make it look like this:

```
<div id="status"></div>
```